# Implementing A3C on TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

After finishing Coursera's Practical RL course on A3C, I'm trying to implement my own A3C agent using tensorflow 2. To start, I'm training it on the Cartpole environment but I can't get good results. For now, I've already launched several training with the following code, changing the entropy coefficient to see its impact (the results are shown below). Does it come from my implementation, or is it more a fine-tuning issue ?

```
class A3C:
  def __init__(self, state_dim, n_actions, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-3)):
    self.state_input = Input(shape=state_dim)
    self.x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(self.state_input)

    self.head_v = Dense(1, activation='linear')(self.x)
    self.head_p = Dense(n_actions, activation='linear')(self.x)

    self.network = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[self.state_input], outputs=[self.head_v, self.head_p])
    self.optimizer = optimizer

  def forward(self, state):
    return self.network(state)

  def sample(self, logits):
    policy = np.exp(logits.numpy()) / np.sum(np.exp(logits.numpy()), axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    return np.array([np.random.choice(len(p), p=p) for p in policy])

def evaluate(agent, env, n_games=1): """Plays an a game from start till done, returns per-game rewards """
  game_rewards = []
  for _ in range(n_games):
    state = env.reset()

    total_reward = 0
    while True:
      action = agent.sample(agent.forward(np.array([state]))[1])[0]
      state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
      total_reward += reward
      if done: break

    game_rewards.append(total_reward)
  return game_rewards

class EnvBatch:
  def __init__(self, n_envs = 10):
    self.envs = [gym.make(env_id) for _ in range(n_envs)]
    
  def reset(self):
    return np.array([env.reset() for env in self.envs])

  def step(self, actions):
    results = [env.step(a) for env, a in zip(self.envs, actions)]
    new_obs, rewards, done, infos = map(np.array, zip(*results))
    
    for i in range(len(self.envs)):
      if done[i]:
        new_obs[i] = self.envs[i].reset()
    
    return new_obs, rewards, done, infos

 

env_id = "CartPole-v0"
env = gym.make(env_id)
state_dim = env.observation_space.shape
n_actions = env.action_space.n
agent = A3C(state_dim, n_actions)    
env_batch = EnvBatch(10)
batch_states = env_batch.reset()
gamma=0.99

rewards_history = []
entropy_history = []

for i in trange(200000):
  with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    batch_values, batch_logits = agent.forward(batch_states)
    batch_actions = agent.sample(batch_logits)
    batch_next_states, batch_rewards, batch_dones, _ = env_batch.step(batch_actions)
    batch_next_values, btach_next_logits = agent.forward(batch_next_states)
    batch_next_values *= (1 - batch_dones)

    probs = tf.nn.softmax(batch_logits)
    logprobs = tf.nn.log_softmax(batch_logits)

    logp_actions = tf.reduce_sum(logprobs * tf.one_hot(batch_actions, n_actions), axis=-1)

    advantage = batch_rewards + gamma*batch_next_values - batch_values
    entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(probs * logprobs, 1, name="entropy")

    actor_loss =  - tf.reduce_mean(logp_actions * tf.stop_gradient(advantage)) - 0.005 * tf.reduce_mean(entropy)

    target_state_values = batch_rewards + gamma*batch_next_values
    critic_loss = tf.reduce_mean((batch_values - tf.stop_gradient(target_state_values))**2 )

    loss = actor_loss + critic_loss

  var_list = agent.network.trainable_variables
  grads = t.gradient(loss,var_list)
  agent.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, var_list))
  batch_states = batch_next_states

  entropy_history.append(np.mean(entropy))

  if i % 500 == 0:
    if i % 2500 == 0:
      rewards_history.append(np.mean(evaluate(agent, env, n_games=3)))

    clear_output(True)
    plt.figure(figsize=[8, 4])
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.plot(rewards_history, label='rewards')
    plt.title("Session rewards")
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()

    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.plot(entropy_history, label='entropy')
    plt.title("Policy entropy")
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

1. [Beta = 0.005 - Training 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIxQO.png)
2. [Beta = 0.005 - Training 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBxJ4.png)
3. [Beta = 0.005 - Training 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW657.png)
4. [Beta = 0.05 - Training 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZN8i.png)
5. [Beta = 0.05 - Training 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ0p2.png)
6. [Beta = 0.05 - Training 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrd8U.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've looked through your code, and it doesn't look like there's any problem with the algorithm. That is, it seems to me that the Hyper Parameter was chosen incorrectly. Try different Hyper Parameter Sets. If it doesn't work properly, refer to [repository](https://github.com/marload/deep-rl-tf2)

Answer (score 0):

The critic loss is wrong. You should get first expect returns, predicting the next state and iterate over it with bellman equation.
Here is an example:

```
def getExpectedReturns(self, states, next_states, done, rewards, standarize=True):
    # Get next value
    if done[-1] == 1.0:
        arr_idx = np.zeros((rewards.shape[0], 1))
        arr_idx[-1] = 1.0
        values_rewards_sum_one_hot = tf.convert_to_tensor(arr_idx, dtype=tf.float32)
        next_value = tf.reduce_sum(rewards * values_rewards_sum_one_hot, axis=0)
    else:
        values_rewards_sum = self.model_a2c(next_states)[-1]
        arr_idx = np.zeros((rewards.shape[0], 1))
        arr_idx[0] = 1.0
        values_rewards_sum_one_hot = tf.convert_to_tensor(arr_idx, dtype=tf.float32)
        next_value = tf.reduce_sum(values_rewards_sum * values_rewards_sum_one_hot, axis=0)
    
    # Iterate over rewards         
    list_true_values = []
    for i in reversed(range(0, len(rewards))):
        if done[i]==0.0:
            next_value = rewards[i] + next_value * self.gamma
        else:
            next_value = rewards[i]
        list_true_values.append(next_value)
    list_true_values.reverse()
    list_true_values = tf.convert_to_tensor(list_true_values, dtype=tf.float32)

    
    if standarize:
        list_true_values = ((list_true_values - tf.math.reduce_mean(list_true_values)) / 
                   (tf.math.reduce_std(list_true_values) + tf.constant(1e-12)))
    
    return list_true_values




with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        # Advantage            
        returns = self.getExpectedReturns(states, next_states, done, rewards, standarize=False)
        actions_probs_logits, values = self.model_a2c(states)
        advantage = returns - values
        advantage = tf.squeeze(advantage)
        
        # Actions probs
        actions_probs_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(actions_probs_logits)
        actions_log_probs_softmax = tf.nn.log_softmax(actions_probs_logits) 
        actions_one_hot = tf.one_hot(actions, self.num_actions, 1.0, 0.0)
        actions_log_probs = tf.reduce_sum(actions_log_probs_softmax * actions_one_hot, axis=-1)

        # Entropy
        entropy = self.entropy_coef * tf.reduce_mean(actions_probs_softmax * actions_log_probs_softmax, axis=1)

        # Losses
        actor_loss = -tf.reduce_mean(actions_log_probs * tf.stop_gradient(advantage), axis=0)
        critic_loss = self.critic_coef * tf.reduce_mean(tf.math.pow(advantage, 2), axis=0)
        total_loss = actor_loss + critic_loss - entropy
```